# Is there a way to make Selenium or Facebook Webdriver slow down so that tests are observable?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, phpunit, functional-testing, user-experience

While the vast majority of the time I'm happy to have the browser tests running fast (and headless), on occasion it would be extremely valuable to be able to pass a switch to the tests that slowed the process down and maybe even highlighted the mouse before clicking.

The largest use case for this is demonstrating and communicating the value of said tests to decision makers--something that is hard to do when the windows cycle so quickly they can't begin to understand what is happening.

Comment: you can add `time.sleep()` after each step or just to use `InternetExplorer` webdriver :))

Comment: Hah! IE to the rescue. Really though, adding sleep to everything would be a pretty significant investment in crufty code. I'm hoping for a more elegant option.

Answer (score 3):

Hi please do it like below

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
EventFiringWebDriver slowDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver); 
slowDriver.registerListener(new ListenerThatAddsPauses(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
```

You will have to write your class ListenerThatAddsPauses which will extend AbstractEventFiringListener. In ListenerThatAddsPauses you will have to override methods from parent class and for example add needed pauses. Something like:

```
@Override
public void beforeClickOn(WebElement element, WebDriver driver) {
   Thread.sleep(timeout);
}
```

also here i found a example please have a look at it may be this helps you http://seleniumworks.blogspot.in/2014/02/eventfiringwebdriver.html

Answer (score 1):

Install VNC on your selenium server then you can just watch them happen.

If you want to slow it down you could do a sleep(1) in a core framework function such as click() or whatnot, to slow down even further.

Comment: I know how to make them headless or not; the question is more about a way to set a config option or the like in order to slow it down.